# Can`t create and copy the file

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask

My program should work as follows:

```
1.Copy the new database in the program folder
2.Import the records from the old database to the new one.
```

But I for some reason get an exception. Why?

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

        String LOCAL_DATABASE_PATH = getApplicationInfo().dataDir + File.separator +
                "databases" + File.separator;


        File fileDir = new File(LOCAL_DATABASE_PATH);
        if (!fileDir.exists())
            fileDir.mkdirs();

        File tempFile = new File(LOCAL_DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);

        try {
            tempFile.createNewFile(); // here I catch exception

            InputStream is = SplashActivity.this.getAssets().open(
                    DATABASE_NAME);
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    LOCAL_DATABASE_PATH, DATABASE_NAME));

            int bufferLength = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

            while ((bufferLength = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }

            Preferences.getInstance(SplashActivity.this).
                    set(Preferences.IS_DATABASE_COPYING_ON_DEVICE, true);

            is.close();
            os.close();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am getting the following error

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-28 09:32:27.977  32558-32558/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_hawaii.so
08-28 09:32:27.977  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
08-28 09:32:27.977  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ at com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.SplashActivity$DataBaseLoadTask.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:73)
08-28 09:32:27.977  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-28 09:32:27.977  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-28 09:32:27.977  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-28 09:32:27.977  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-28 09:32:27.977  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-28 09:32:27.977  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-28 09:32:27.987  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-28 09:32:27.987  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
08-28 09:32:27.987  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
08-28 09:32:27.987  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:941)
08-28 09:32:27.987  32558-32587/com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest W/System.err﹕ ... 7 more
```

Comment: Did you obtain permission to write files?

Comment: Yes, of course, I added all permissions

Comment: Show your manifest.xml file

Comment: The doc says that createNewFile() only throws exception if it's not possible to create the file. Perhaps you should check if it already exists?

Comment: Or if it is readonly?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I just notice you don't even use tempFile. Why don't you just remove it??

Comment: No, I copy the file before calling createNewFile() does not exist in the folder /databases, I checked it out in the Total Comander

Comment: I don't see any copy operation. Perhaps you should put in all your code if you want to get a proper answer.

Comment: InputStream is = SplashActivity.this.getAssets().open(
                    DATABASE_NAME);
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    LOCAL_DATABASE_PATH, DATABASE_NAME));

            int bufferLength = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

            while ((bufferLength = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }

Comment: Fist: edit you question and put the code in there so everybody can read it. Second: Still no appearance of tempFile.

Comment: John Doe - I do not understand you. Code to copy a file - 100% working, already tested - is working properly. What do not you understand?

Comment: You are creating a new File Objekt named tempFile. You call its method tempFile.createNewFile(). But you never use tempFile again. Instead you create new files with the same path and name. When you open a file then you should use it and not open it somewhere else.

Comment: I change code:  FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempFile); and now I use tempFile, but tempFile.createNewFile() still throw exception

Comment: I'm thinking - it may be associated with the device as root? Just this code worked fine on the emulator.

Comment: Did you also try to check if tempFile already exits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the `tempFile` try using the `fileDir` you already created to get sure it exists.

```
File tempFile = new File(fileDir, DATABASE_NAME);
```

Before you create a new file you should check if it already exists by calling its `exits()` method. And then instead of opening it again you should actually keep on using it. Or at least close it before opening again.

```
if(!tempFile.exists())
   tempFile.createNewFile();

InputStream is = SplashActivity.this.getAssets().open(
                 DATABASE_NAME);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
```

Create you `FileOutPutStream` using the `tempFile` or close `tempFile` to get sure your file is not locked.

Comment: I still go the same exception

Comment: so does your code enter the tempFile.creaNewFile() line meaning the file didn't exist? Could you debug you code and tell me exactly where the exception is being thrown?

Comment: Takes exception when calling createNewFile(). Through Total Comander, I see that the file is not present within the program